# Use the change of variables to evaluate the double-integral $\iint_R4(x+y)e^{x-y}\;dA$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Use the change of variables indicated to evaluate the double-integral $\iint_R4(x+y)e^{x-y}\;dA$ where $R$ is the interior of the triangle whose vertices are $(-1,1)$, $(0,0)$, and $(1,1)$; $x=\frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}(u-v)$

I know I have to find the following components for the formula:

$$\iint_S f(g(u,v),h(u,v)) \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v,)}\right| \ du \; dv$$

The Jacobian is $\frac{1}{2}$

Next I replaced $x$ and $y$ in my integral with the change of variable to give me the following double integral:

$$\iint 4\left[\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2}+\frac{u}{2}-\frac{v}{2}\right]
e^{\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2}-\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2}}\;\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\;du\;dv$$

After simplifying the above I got:

$$2\iint ue^v\;du\;dv$$

I'm completely confused with how to map $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ so that I can identify my limits of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken:

Notice how

$$u = x +y \qquad \text{and} \qquad v = x-y.$$

Then notice how $v = \alpha$ implies parallell lines to the first bisector of the plane. This means $v = 0$ results in the first bisector.
Furthermore $u =0$ results in the second bisector.
All that is remaining is the straight line $y = 1$. You can write this using the variables $u$ and $v$ as $1 = \dfrac{1}{2}(u-v)$ or $2 = u-v$.

This all implies the following:

Let $$v: 0\to u-2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad u = 0 \to 2.$$

Added picture:
[image: Graphical display]

By using the change of variables you integrate along the red arrows. 
These red arrows start at $v = 0$, but and stop at $v = y-2$. Integration goes as follow:
$$\int_0^2 \operatorname du \int_0^{u-2} \operatorname dv$$

For example: At $u=0$ (the first red arrow) integration goes from $v = 0$ to $v = 0-2 = -2$ (or $x-y = -2$ or $y = x+2$ the blue line).

At $u =1$ (the second red arrow) integrations goes from $v=0$ to $v = 1-2 = -1$ (or $x-y = -1$ or $y = x+1$ the pink line).

When $u \approx 2$ then integration goes from $v=0$ to $v \approx 2-2 =0$ or the red arrow is getting tiny small.

Comment: Is it also correct to take the relationships you formed where $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$ to get the mapping of points on the $uv$ plane?  For example, I plugged in all the $(x,y)$ points into $u=x=y$ and $v=x-y$ and get the following $(u,v)$ points: $(-1,1) \rightarrow (0,-2)$, $(0,0) \rightarrow (0,0)$, and $(1,1) \rightarrow (2,0)$

Comment: plugging in the points is a good method to get a feel of bounds, but you can't use the bounds $u: 0\to 2$ and $v:0\to -2$ because of the bounding line $y= 1$. I'm working on a picture which will clarify the bounds :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to the picture for clarification!  So I have the following bounds for my limits of integration: $0 \le u \le 2$ and $-2 \le v \le 0$?

Comment: Oh... I guess I cannot use those bounds... waiting for your picture lol

Comment: If you would use those bounds above then the surface would be a square (which is not the figure you want). Have you seen how you can have a variable as an upper bound? (like the $u-2$ in the integral)

Comment: I'm studying your picture.  How is it that $v=u-2$?  Also, I've seen variables in the bounds before :-)

Comment: Since $y=1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(u-v) = 1\Leftrightarrow u-v = 2\Leftrightarrow v = u-2$ ;)

Comment: Oh now I see.  Since $y=1$ is the upper bound of the triangle, you set the equation equal to that to figure out where the upper bound of $v$ is?

Comment: The light bulb has gone off.  Now I can 'see' what and why we are doing the change in variables!

Comment: You see how you can find $u=2$ as upper bound? BTW you could easily integrate in a different order, can you figure out the question marks? $$\int_0^? \operatorname dv \int_0^? \operatorname du$$

Comment: Would it be:  $$\int^{2}_{0}\;dv \int^{v+2}_{0}\;du$$

Comment: I think you got the order mixed up, evaluating the integral above would result in an expression containing the variable $v$. I guess you mean: $$\int_0^2\operatorname d v \int_0^{v+2} \operatorname d u.$$ While the bounds at variable $u$ are correct, these at variable $v$ aren't. $v = 2$ is equivalent with $x-y=2$ or $y = x-2$ but you need $y = x+2$! BTW: It's a fun exercise to calculate the integral twice using both bounds and see that the end result is the same. (Or so it should be, according to Fubini-Toneli)